# No respond from WebSocket after request connection from browser to C# program

Tags: javascript, c#, html, tcp, websocket

I'm learning how to get my C# program communicate with browser.
I'm using TCP in C# and WebSocket in my HTML5 browser.

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace ShouldWork
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TCPServer server = new TCPServer();
        System.Threading.Thread obj_thread = new System.Threading.Thread(server.startServer);
        obj_thread.Start();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 7000);
        NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
        byte[] data_tosend = createDataPacket(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tx_data_send.Text));
        ns.Write(data_tosend, 0, data_tosend.Length);
    }

    private byte[] createDataPacket(byte[] data)
    {
        byte[] initialize = new byte[1];
        initialize[0] = 2;
        byte[] separator = new byte[1];
        separator[0] = 4;
        byte[] datalength = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(data.Length));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ms.Write(initialize, 0, initialize.Length);
        ms.Write(datalength, 0, datalength.Length);
        ms.Write(separator, 0, separator.Length);
        ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

class TCPServer
{
    TcpListener listener;
    public TCPServer()
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 7000);
    }

    public void startServer()
    {
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
            if(ns.ReadByte() == 2)
            {
                byte[] recv_data = readStream(ns);
                Form1.ActiveForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    ((TextBox)Form1.ActiveForm.Controls.Find("tx_recv_data", true)[0]).Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recv_data);
                }));
            }
        }
    }

    public byte[] readStream(NetworkStream ns)
    {
        byte[] data_buff = null;

        int b = 0;
        String buff_length = "";

        while ((b = ns.ReadByte()) != 4)
        {
            buff_length += (char)b;
        }
        int data_length = Convert.ToInt32(buff_length);
        data_buff = new byte[data_length];
        int byte_read = 0;
        int byte_offset = 0;
        while (byte_offset < data_length)
        {
            byte_read = ns.Read(data_buff, byte_offset, data_length - byte_offset);
            byte_offset += byte_read;
        }

        return data_buff;
    }
}
}
```

**UI**

When user clicks Start Server button, the program would then start the TCPServer. Then we can enter some text in the second textbox and my code will then process it and display the message on the first textbox.

[image: UI]

Now I'd like to move the client part to the browser, so I created a simple web app and test out connection.

**Code snippet**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Socket demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="testWebSocket()">Connect to C# server</button><br><br>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function testWebSocket(){

  var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:7000');
  console.log("ssss");

  socket.onopen = function(){
    console.log("on open");
    socket.send("Hello");
  }

  socket.onclose = function(evt){
    console.log("on close");
  }

  socket.onerror = function(evt){
    console.log("on error");
    console.log(evt.data);
  }
}

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what's wrong..... the onopen function doesn't seems to work at all, chrome console does display "sss" and that's it....

Is there something wrong with the approach I'm using?

Comment: A WebSocket is a bit more than just a simple tcp connection. It is initiated as a HTTP request and then "upgraded" to a WebSocket, so your server logic need to support that. I suggest you read up on the WebSocket protocol and connection flow.

Comment: Or, get a webSocket server library for C# that already supports the connection protocol and data format and build with that.

Comment: @jishi oh I see, alright will try to read up more.

Comment: @jfriend00 Can you suggest me some of the library? I tried SocketIoClientDotNet but it was not helpful

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, WebSocket uses its own framing schema.

Take a look to this link: https://hpbn.co/websocket/, specially the part where the framing is explained: https://hpbn.co/websocket/#binary-framing-layer

The reason why the connection never gets open, is because it is unable of completing the handshake : https://hpbn.co/websocket/#http-upgrade-negotiation